# Is it possible to generate just a package-lock.json file without doing an npm install?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I need to generate just a package-lock.json file, but I don't want to rerun npm install.

Is it possible just to generate this lock file without it reinstalling any of my package files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `npm shrinkwrap` and rename the file afterward. [source](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/672)

---

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, renaming may be useless as [package-locks doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks) :

> npm uses package-lock.json or, if present, npm-shrinkwrap.json

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll have to look at how shrinkwrap works

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `--package-lock-only` argument:

```
npm install --package-lock-only
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> The **--package-lock-only** argument will only update the **package-lock.json**, instead of checking **node_modules** and downloading dependencies.